# Uploading indexedDB data to PHP in a loop

Tags: php, javascript, json, indexeddb

I am trying to use indexedDB to store offline data, and then upload the data when connected. In the following code a loop is used to read the data from indexedDB, and for each record (object) in the table (store), a JSON object is created and posted to a PHP file. However, this indexedDB loop only executes once. Is this because the JSON object was sent to server asynchronously?

```
var trans = LocalDB.indexedDB.db.transaction(storename, 
                                             IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
var store = trans.objectStore(storename);
var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0);
var cursorRequest = store.openCursor(keyRange);

cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var result = e.target.result;
    var obj = new Object;
    obj.name = result.value.Name;
    obj.Date = result.value.Date;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);//problem: only shown once
            result.continue();
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "upload.php");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
};
cursorRequest.onerror = function (e) { alert("Error uploading"); };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your Console for errors, you'll probably see an:

```
Uncaught Error: TransactionInactiveError
```

This does seem to be due to the Ajax request delaying the `result.continue()`. In the meantime, the transaction apparently becomes inactive and can no longer be used by the cursor.

You'll want to move the `result.continue()` out of the `onreadystatechange`:

```
// ...
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
result.continue();
```

You could also opt for *S*jax (synchronous). But, that's not generally recommended.

---

Also, note that the `onsuccess` callback will be called an additional time with a `null` `result` to signify the cursor has completed, so you'll want to test for this:

```
cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var result = e.target.result;

    if (!result) {
        console.log('Done');
        return; // exit callback
    }

    // ...
};
```

You could also use this to send the entire collection in an `Array` with a single Ajax request:

```
var storedCollection = [];

cursorResult.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var result = e.target.result;

    if (result) {
        storedCollection.push(result.value);
        result.continue();
        return; // exit callback
    }

    // else: the cursor is "done"

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // ...
    xml.send(JSON.stringify(storedCollection));
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CZBrd/ (check Console)

Comment: Thanks. Agree with you, I thought if the problem could not be easily fixed then I should post a object array to php.